# Is it possible for notification to do search?

Tags: android

I'm working on a movie app that notifies you when there is an upcoming movie. But I'm focused on when someone sends a movie recommendation it shows a notification and when it is clicked it search and display the movie. is that possible? How?

Comment: Hey there, welcome to Stack Overflow! Your question is pretty broad and opinion-based, so it's unlikely you'll receive good answers. There's just so many parts to making a good movie-browsing app that we can't help you very well! A good place to begin is by reviewing Android's SDK on how to create notifications. RSS feeds are an easy way to collect new data and make it available to client applications. Your question could also use a bit of TLC with a spell-checker. The easiest way is to put it in something like Microsoft Word or OpenOffice Writer before making an edit to your post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use FCM (Firebase Cloud Messaging) to send Push notification from server once user recommend some movie you can send notification through server.
See link for complete detail.
[FCM](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/)

```
Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, YourActivityWhichYouWantToOpen.class);
                notificationIntent.putExtra("movieName", "NameOfRecomendedMoview");
                notificationIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                    .setAutoCancel(true)
                    .setPriority(2)
                    .setTicker(title)
                    .setContentText(body)
                    .setContentIntent(PendingIntent.getActivity(this, iUniqueId, notificationIntent,            PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT))
                    .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
                    .setContentTitle(title)
                    .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL);
                    NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) this
                    .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
                    builder.setLights(Color.GREEN, 500, 500);
                    mNotificationManager.notify(MESSAGE_NOTIFICATION_ID, builder.build());
```

Using new intent in activity you take movie name when user click on notification.

Comment: for the notification part,  i want the notification when its pressed it should search for the specific movie based on the recommendation.. how to do that part ?

Comment: You want when you press notification it open recommended movie?

Comment: If you want that just open desire activity on notification pressed and in payload data pass movie name which user recommend and parse that name when your notification pressed.

Comment: Please accept my answer so it help others as I edit answer for you as well

Comment: ill try this code first . but thanks for helping me, really appreciate it